# Using jquery i18n plugin for i18n?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internationalization

I am using jquery i18n plugin ( http://code.google.com/p/jquery-i18n-properties/ ) to internationalize the messages placed in jquery/js. 
i have below project structure.

[image]

I have `some.js` file in `js` folder and inside `some.js` file i have to refer a properties file which is located in `properties` folder of `src/main/resources` folder. can i do as below? inside `properties` folder of `src/main/resources` folder i have placed `Messages.properties` and `Messages_en_US.properties`. In both the properties files i have placed `myForm.success.msg=Success` property. Now i am trying to access it as below. But below code does not get the value of `myForm.success.msg` key. `instead of giving value, it is giving the key itself but not the value`. Am i referring the properties file wrongly? is my properties file referring correct? Please help me.

### JSP code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./public/js/some.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./public/js/jquery.i18n.properties-min-1.0.9.js"></script>
```

### some.js

```
jQuery.i18n.properties({
    name:'Messages', 
    path:'properties/',  //as i have properties file in properties folder of src/main/resources 
    mode:'both',
    callback: function() {
    alert("message "+jQuery.i18n.prop('myForm.success.msg'));
}

});
```

Comment: You have to give more details about the code in other files you are referring to.

However I would encourage you to use MessageFormat plugin instead jQuery.i18n. I've described this plugin here: https://developer.tizen.org/documentation/articles/plural-and-gender-rules-internationalized-applications

Comment: Same issue with me. Is your issue resolved

Answer (score 0):

I don't try it but I think you should put the `*.properties` files in `public/resources` directory.

And the path shoud be:

```
jQuery.i18n.properties({
    name:'Messages', 
    path:'../resources/', // changed here 
    mode:'both',
    callback: function() {
    alert("message "+jQuery.i18n.prop('myForm.success.msg'));
}
```

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy your app to a server, eg. Tomcat, and then access to the pages by server.
The root cause of your problem is a html page can't access to properties files across domain.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that will not work. The JQuery plugin will always look for a properties file that are within the `webcontent` folder. Try this instead:

1. Copy those properties file inside your webapp folder and test it with actual path. e.g. `resources/custom/i18n/` [Note - Here I placed the properties file inside a `i18n` folder and placed a `resources` folder under `webapp`]. This will fix your problem!
2. Now we can manage two files, but do we really need it? The easiest thing to do is have your file only in the `src/main/resources` folder, but as part of your build step copy this properties file to your second location (i.e. inside the `webapp` folder).